# Executing a function when an operation has completed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working in node JavaScript and am trying to run a new function when a past loop has completed. In the code below, `// loop through objects in data, to process it` is used to represent the basic for loop through the data, where the data is appended to an array.

With each response, z is increased by one. However, I often find that z reaches 40 before the data has been processed sometimes. I cannot put z inside the loop, as there are many objects inside each page.

Could anyone suggest a method of only increasing z and checking it is equal to 40 after the loop has completed?

```
var req = http.request(headers, function(response) {
    response.on('error', function (e) {
        //
    })
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        //
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
        // loop through objects in data, to process it
        z++
        if (z == 40) {
            newFunction(values, totals)
        };
    });
})
req.on('error', function(e) {
    //
})
req.end();
```

Comment: "Could anyone suggest a method of only increasing z and checking it is equal to 40 after the loop has completed?" That's what you already do, assuming your loop is where your comment is. If your loop triggers some asynchronous tasks, those tasks completing have nothing to do with the loop completing.

Comment: Can you provide some more concrete details. *"the data has been processed"*: which data? in which code? If your problem is related to data being processed or not, it is essential you provide the relevant code.

Comment: @trincot The data received from the HTTP request gets processed, but this is often after the "if (z == 40) {}" conditional returns true. I want the "if (z == 40) {}" conditional to run after the data is put into an array / processed.

Comment: I am asking for the code. Add it to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with trincot, I would ask you to be a bit more specific.
But from what I gather you could try using async.each().
http://justinklemm.com/node-js-async-tutorial/

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop for each response, compare the number of objects processed to the total number of objects in the response. Only increment z when that number has been reached.

```
loop through responses
  loop through objects in single response
    if ( data.length === counter) {
      z ++;
    }
    counter ++;
  }
  if ( 40 === z ) {
    newFunction(values, totals);
  }
}
```

Comment: Async is your friend :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using async.timesSeries from the popular async module!

Link: https://github.com/caolan/async#times

Example Code :)

```
// Required NPM Modules
var async = require('async')

// Run Async Times Series Function
// Will execute 40 times then make the final callback
async.timesSeries(40, asyncOperation, asyncTimesCallback)


/**
 * This is the primary operation that will run 40 times
 * @param {Number} n - Sort of like the index so if its running 40 times and its the last time its running its gonna be 39 or 40 not sure you may have to test that
 * @param {Function} next - Callback function when operation is complete see async times docs or example in this code
 */
function asyncOperation (n, next){

    var req = http.request(headers, function(response) {
        response.on('error', function (e) {
            return next(e, null)
        })
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            //
        })
        response.on('end', function() {
            // loop through objects in data, to process it
            return next(null, 'some value?')
        })
    })
    req.on('error', function(e) {
        return next(e, null)
    })
    req.end()

}


/**
 * This is run after the async operation is complete
 */
function asyncTimesCallback (err, results) {

    // Error Checking?
    if(err) {
        throw new Error(err)
    }

    // function to run wen operation is complete
    newFunction(results['values'], results['totals'])

}


/**
 * New Function The Callback Function Calls
 */
function newFunction(values, totals){

    console.log('Values', values)
    console.log('Totals', totals)

}
```